# How do I add more commands to the HUD?

Tags: hud

**Q:** 
How can I add more commands to the HUD's visibility? Can I make custom HUD commands for individual apps?

**Problem:**
I noticed on HUD supported programs, like firefox and others, there are some commands that the HUD doesn't see. 
Like gedit can close individual text tabs, but not the whole program itself, unlike Chrome which does give the HUD this option. This is just one of many examples. The goal should be that the HUD can control all functions and options of the program. One ring to rule them all, find them all, bind them, ... etc etc.. .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually HUD can access all the menu items of sported programs. In order to take full advantage of HUD you need to be familiar with menu items of specific program you are using.

For example: HUD can close Gedit, The command to close Gedit is "quit" not "close". "close" will only close the individual tabs because that's the default behavior of Gedit.

[image]

You can go further with HUD, Instead of typing the command name you can type the menu name and HUD will display the items of that specific menu. e.g hare's a file menu of Gedit.

[image]

And even further into nested menus:

[image]

But you'll need this only when you don't remember the exact command but know about the menu of that command.

That's not all, The HUD also remembers your interactions with each application over the last 30 days, And uses this information to learn your likely behavior and adapt the results prioritizing the functions most relevant to *you*. [Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/hud-new-unity-feature/)

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'll have to figure out why some commands don't seem to work in the HUD, but I guess I'll tackle those on a case-by-case basis. edit: Like Libre Office, with the HUD plugin, lets you do almost everything except set font formatting, like strike through, double underline (accounting), and others.

Comment: HUD simply searches the 'File, edit, view etc.' menus which usually appear at the top of the screen - it doesn't have any commands 'of its own' per se. If Libreoffice has no menu entry for what you want, then neither will the HUD. In the case of font formatting, there is no menu entry for bold, underline, strikethrough etc as they're toolbar buttons which the HUD doesn't read. For example, you cannot go to the file menu and find strikethrough or the edit menu and find bold.

Comment: @Isaac You can file bugs about HUD [hare](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu).

Comment: You see, I'd love to add functions to the hud for things the hud can't normally see. That would be very cool.

Comment: @Isaac Well the future of HUD is very bright. So keep your fingers crossed. Read the end of this [article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/hud-new-unity-feature/)